# Network game - works as a separate application but hangs when started from another application

Tags: sockets, program-entry-point, freeze

I have a simple network chess game which works fine when I start it as a separate application. But when I start it from a button from another application the game hangs when the client of the chess server trys to connect to the chess server. It seems that the program works when the ChessStart object is made in the main(...) method. But when it is made in actionPerformed()  something happens.

this is how it is started from the button

```
 chessButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());    
                        ChessStart frame = new ChessStart();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and here is the class started as a separate application (I use exactly the same code as above but here it is in the main method.

```
public class ChessStart extends JFrame implements Runnable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7926472295620076147L;

private JPanel contentPane;
static Socket s;
  ObjectOutputStream oops;
  ObjectInputStream oips;
  ChessGameDemo1 chess;
  Thread tred, serThread;
  boolean title;
  private JTextField serversIPField;
  ServerSocket serSocket;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());    
                ChessStart frame = new ChessStart();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public ChessStart() {
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            try {
                oops.close();
                oips.close();
                s.close();
                serSocket.close();
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {System.exit(1);}
        }
    });

     chess=new ChessGameDemo1();    
     chess.setTitle("Click one of the buttons!");    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle(" NikiFin Chess");
    setBounds(100, 100, 497, 196);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);    
    tred=new Thread(this);

    JButton startServerButton = new JButton("Start server");
    startServerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

              chess.setTitle("Waiting for connection....");             
              title=true;
                  try { 

                      serThread=new Thread(new ServerThread(chess, tred));
                      serThread.start();                  
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception from accept socket: " + e); 
                      System.exit(1);
                  }
        }
    });
    startServerButton.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
    startServerButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    startServerButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    startServerButton.setBounds(10, 5, 143, 29);
    contentPane.add(startServerButton);

    JButton connectToServerButton = new JButton("Connect to server");

    connectToServerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                title=true;
                String ip1=serversIPField.getText();
                String ip=removeIntervals(ip1);
                s = new Socket(ip,7777);
                ChessGameDemo1.color="black";
                oips = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                chess.myFigures = ((ArrayList<Figure>)oips.readObject()); 
                chess.changePosition();
                chess.repaint();
                oops = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                oops.writeObject(chess.myFigures);    
                chess.setTitle("The other part's turn");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception from connect to server socket: " + ex); 
                System.exit(1);
            }
                chess.ready=true;
                dispose();
                tred.start();

        }
    });


    connectToServerButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    connectToServerButton.setBounds(10, 40, 143, 29);
    contentPane.add(connectToServerButton);

    serversIPField = new JTextField();
    serversIPField.setBounds(360, 43, 113, 24);
    contentPane.add(serversIPField);
    serversIPField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("To join a game, play black.    Server IP:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(161, 45, 195, 21);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("To start a new game wainting for a partner, play white.");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(161, 8, 310, 22);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JTextArea txtrToPlayThe = new JTextArea();
    txtrToPlayThe.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    txtrToPlayThe.setText("To play the server must be started first. The other part must know the server's \r\nIP address. To get it can be used the button Whois. Mark the name of the \r\nuser started the  server and klick Whois button. This will give you the server's \r\nIP address. Enter it in the blank field and click Connect to server. Have fun!");
    txtrToPlayThe.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
    txtrToPlayThe.setBounds(5, 80, 475, 69);
    contentPane.add(txtrToPlayThe);

    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
    img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/chess.png"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     try {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
setIconImage(img);

}
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            oips = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            chess.myFigures = ((ArrayList<Figure>)oips.readObject());    
            chess.changePosition();
            chess.setTitle("Now is your turn!");
            chess.ready = true;
            if(title)   {
                chess.setTitle("Ready!"); 
                title=false; 
            } 

            chess.repaint();

        } catch (Exception ex) {                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception in input stream: " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

      try {

           while (chess.ready) 
               Thread.sleep(100); 


        oops = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        oops.writeObject(chess.myFigures);    
        chess.setTitle("The other part's turn");

        } catch (Exception ex) {                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception in output stream: " + ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }         
}
```

and here is the socket thread

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

ChessGameDemo1 chess;
ServerSocket serSocket;
Socket s;
Thread tread;
ObjectOutputStream oops;
ObjectInputStream oips;

public ServerThread(ChessGameDemo1 ches, Thread tred) {
    chess=ches;
    tread=tred;
}

public void run() { 
    try {   
      serSocket=new ServerSocket(7777);
      ChessStart.s = serSocket.accept();        
      ChessGameDemo1.color="white";
      chess.setTitle("White to play!");  
      oops = new ObjectOutputStream(ChessStart.s.getOutputStream());
      oops.writeObject(chess.myFigures);
      tread.start();    
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(1);
    }


}
```

}

is it possible the problem to from

static Socket s;

and if yes how can I fix most painless?

Is there any difference in making object in main method and in another method?